# Can't figure out why this is dead code

Tags: java

Code so far:

```
@Override
public Double getNotaMedia() {
    Double notaAux = 0.0;
    int aux1 = this.notas.size();
    int aux3 = 0;

    if(!this.notas.isEmpty()){
        for (int aux2 = 0; aux2 <= aux1; aux2++){
            if(this.notas.get(aux2).getValorNota() >= 5.0){
                notaAux += this.notas.get(aux2).getValorNota();
                aux3 = aux3 + 1;
            }
            return notaAux.doubleValue() / aux3;
        }
    }
    return notaAux;
}
```

According to Eclipse the `aux2++` is dead code and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a `return` statement at the end of your `for`-loop body, so the increment `aux2++` will never be executed since the function will return before the next loop iteration begins (or, more specifically, before the first one fully ends).

Comment: Right, the return needs to be between the two other brackets! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (int aux2 = 0; aux2 <= aux1; aux2++){
        if(this.notas.get(aux2).getValorNota() >= 5.0){
            notaAux += this.notas.get(aux2).getValorNota();
            aux3 = aux3 + 1;
        }
        return notaAux.doubleValue() / aux3;
    }
```

In this `for` statement, `aux2++` will be executed after each iteration of the loop completes.  But in this code, the first iteration of the loop (if any) ends with a `return`, which abruptly completes the loop (and the entire method); therefore, the program can never get to the `aux2++` expression.

Is the `return` supposed to be inside the `if`?